# World and Entities are not same in the App and Physics on matter.js

Tags: javascript, react-native, matter.js

I am trying to write a flappy bird game on react native with matter.js. I followed an online tutorial and created a flappy bird game. But I wanted to go further and do something on my own to practice what I have learned from the tutorial. I wanted to create a fire button and when user clicks it, fire is send to the pipes.

[image: When app is opened first time]

This fire sending is working when I run the app first time. But after the game over, user clicks anything and new game is started. This time, fire button doesn't work. I debugged and see that in the App.js file, world and entities are updated. My fire object is created. But I don't see it in the screen. When I checked the entities in the Physics.js, they are not actually created.

Here is the relavent code where I create fires.

```
onFirePress = () => {
    let bird = this.entities.bird.body;
    console.log("bird position:"+bird.position.x, bird.position.y)
    const fireObj = {};

    fireObj["fire" + this.state.fireCounter.toString()] = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
      bird.position.x + 50,
      bird.position.y,
      constants.FIRE_SIZE,
      constants.FIRE_SIZE,
      { isStatic: true },
    );
    let world = this.entities.physics.world;
    Matter.World.add(world, [fireObj["fire" + this.state.fireCounter.toString()]])

    this.entities['fire' + this.state.fireCounter ] = { body: fireObj["fire" + this.state.fireCounter.toString()], renderer: Fire };

    let fireList = Object.keys(this.entities).filter(key => key.slice(0,4) === "fire");
    console.log(fireList);

    this.setState({ fireCounter: this.state.fireCounter + 1 });
  }
```

Here is my reset function in the App.js.

```
  reset = () => {
    this.gameEngine.swap(this.setupWorld());
    this.setState({ running: true, score: 0,  })
  }
```

and render in the App.js.

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image source={Images.background} resizeMode={"stretch"} style={styles.backgroundImage} />
        <GameEngine
          ref={ref => {
            this.gameEngine = ref;
          }}
          style={styles.gameContainer}
          running={this.state.running}
          onEvent={this.onEvent}
          systems={[Physics]}
          entities={this.entities}>
          <StatusBar hidden={true} />
        </GameEngine>
        <Text style={styles.score}>{this.state.score}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.fireButtonWrapper} onPress={this.onFirePress}>
          <Image source={Images.fireButton} style={styles.fireButton} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        {!this.state.running && <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.reset} style={styles.fullScreenButton} >
          <View style={styles.fullScreen} >
            <Text style={styles.sectionTitle} >Game Over!</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>}
      </View>

    );
  }
```

and here is my relevant Physics.js file code.

```
const Physics = (entities, { touches, time, dispatch }) => {
  let engine = entities.physics.engine;
  let world = entities.physics.world;
  let bird = entities.bird.body;
let fireList = Object.keys(entities).filter(key => key.slice(0,4) === "fire");

  if(fireList && fireList.length > 0 && consoleOn){
    console.log(fireList);
    consoleOn = false;
  }

  if (tick % 3 === 0 ){
    if (fireList && fireList.length > 0) {
      fireTurn++;
      fireList.forEach(fire => {
        entities[fire].pose = fireTurn *20
      })
    }
  }

  if (fireList && fireList.length > 0){
    console.log(fireList);
    fireList.forEach(fire => {
      if(entities[fire].body.position.x - constants.FIRE_SIZE/ 2 > constants.MAX_WIDTH){
        delete (entities[fire]);
      }else
        Matter.Body.translate(entities[fire].body, {x:2, y:0})
    })
  }


  Matter.Engine.update(engine, time.delta);

  return entities;
};

export default Physics;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wasn't related to matter-js. It was related to react-native-game-engine and when I go through documentation for both matter-js and react-native-game-engine, I have changed my architecture and created my fire bodies in the Physics as the same object. But while I add them to the gameEngine, I give them a unique name. This way, it worked.